# The mapping $\psi: G\to \int_X\oplus H_x \, d\mu(x)$ given by $\psi(g)=\pi(g)f$ is continuous at $g=1$

Tags: representation-theory

I was trying to prove the following proposition. For the notations, you may want to look at the section Definitions and Notations. Thanks!

**Proposition.**
Let $(\pi_x)_{x\in X}$ be a family of a unitary representations of a topological group $G$ on a Hilbert space $H=H_x$. Suppose that the mapping $x\mapsto \pi_x(g)$ is measurable for each $g\in G$. Then the mapping $\pi: G\to GL \left(\int_X\oplus H_x \, d\mu(x)\right)$ given by  $g\mapsto \pi(g)=\int_X\oplus \pi_x(g) \, d\mu(x)$ is a unitary representation of $G$ on $\int_X\oplus H_x \, d\mu(x).$

For the proof, it is easy to show that $\pi$ is a group homomorphism and $\pi(g)$ is a unitary operator for all $g\in G$.

**My Question.** Let $f\in \int_X\oplus H_x \, d\mu(x)$. How can we show that the mapping $\psi: G\to \int_X\oplus H_x \, d\mu(x)$ given by $\psi(g)=\pi(g)f$ is continuous at $g=1$ ?

**My attempt.** Let $\varepsilon>0$. We need to find an open neighborhood $N$ of $1$ such that 
\begin{align}
g\in N \implies\varepsilon >\|\pi(g)f-f\|^2 & =\int_X\|\big(\pi(g)f\big)(x)-f(x)\|^2 \, d\mu(x) \\[10pt]
& = \int_X\|\pi_x(g)f(x)-f(x)\|^2 \, d\mu(x).
\end{align}
On the other hand, for any $x\in X$, since $\pi_x$ is a representation of $G$ on $H_x$, the mapping from $G$ to $H_x$ given by $g\mapsto \pi_x(g)v$ is continuous at $g=1$ for all $v\in H_x$. So, there is an open neighborhood $N$ of $1$ such that
\begin{align*}
g\in N &\implies \|\pi_x(g)v-v\|<\sqrt{\varepsilon} \qquad \text{for all $v\in H_x$}
\\& \implies \|\pi_x(g)f(x)-f(x)\|^2<\varepsilon \qquad \text{for all $x\in X$}
\end{align*}
But I couldn't combine them.

**Definitions and Notations.**
Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $(X,\mu)$ a positive measure space. Let $L^2_H(X,\mu)$ be the set of all functions $f:X\to H$ satisfying the following two conditions

(a) the complex-valued function on $X$ given by $x\mapsto ( f(x),v )$ is measurable for all $v\in H$, (any function $f:X\to H$  satisfying the property (a) is called measurable.)

$\tag b \int_X\|f(x)\|^2 \, d\mu(x)<\infty.$

We define an inner product $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$ on $L^2_H(X,\mu)$ given by
$$\langle f,g \rangle:=\int_X (f(x),g(x)) \, d\mu(x)\qquad\text{for all $f,g\in L^2_H(X,\mu).$}$$
which makes that $L^2_H(X,\mu)$ is a Hilbert space. The Hilbert space $L^2_H(X,\mu)$ is called the **direct integral** of Hilbert spaces $H_x=H$, and this is denoted by
$$L^2_H(X,\mu)=\int_X\oplus H_x \, d\mu(x).$$ 
An element $f\in L^2_H(X,\mu)$ is denoted symbolically thus:
\begin{align}\label{pg}
f=\int_X\oplus f(x) \, d\mu(x)
\end{align}

Let $A$ be a function on $X$, whose value $A(x)$ is a bounded linear operator on $H_x$, such that the function $X\to H$ given by $x\mapsto A(x)f(x)$ is measurable for all $f\in\int_X\oplus H_x\, d\mu(x)$. Suppose that $\|A(x)\|$ is essentially bounded and put $\operatorname{ess sup}_{x\in X}\|A(x)\|=M.$ Then $\int_X\oplus A(x)f(x) \, d\mu(x)\in \int_X \oplus H_x \, d\mu(x)$ because we have
$$\int_X\|A(x)f(x)\|^2 \, d\mu(x)\leq M^2\int_X \|f(x)\|^2 \, d\mu(x) = M^2\|f\|^2 < \infty.$$
So we may define a bounded linear operator 
$$T:\int_X\oplus H_x \, d\mu(x)\to \int_X\oplus H_x \, d\mu(x), \qquad \text{$Tf=\int_X\oplus A(x)f(x) \, d\mu(x).$}$$
Such an operator $T$ is denoted by 
$$T:=\int_X\oplus A(x) \, d\mu(x).$$